# Spring Cloud Contract consumer side test returns 404

Tags: wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

While running Spring Contract test on consumer side using stubs. I got following response first for endpoint creation then for request that was sent to it and then for the response.

Both type1 and type2 are enum fields, the other fields are string.

127.0.0.1 - POST /mappings

```
Connection: [keep-alive]
User-Agent: [Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11.0.5)]
Host: [localhost:11291]
Content-Length: [834]
Content-Type: [text/plain; charset=UTF-8]
{
  "id" : "7d0b6496-be88-43c0-891d-bdb8ef8ae033",
  "request" : {
    "url" : "/testEndpoint",
    "method" : "PUT",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : {
        "matches" : "application/json;charset=UTF-8.*"
      }
    },
    "bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.['name'] == 'Test')]"
    }, {
      "matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.['type1'] == 'NONE')]"
    }, {
      "matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.['type2'] == 'NONE')]"
    }, {
      "matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.['description'] == null)]"
    }, {
      "matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.['comment1'] == null)]"
    }, {
      "matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.['comment2'] == null)]"
    } ]
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 201,
    "transformers" : [ "response-template" ]
  },
  "uuid" : "7d0b6496-be88-43c0-891d-bdb8ef8ae033"
}
```

127.0.0.1 - PUT /testEndpoint

```
Connection: [keep-alive]
User-Agent: [Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11.0.5)]
Host: [localhost:11291]
Accept-Encoding: [gzip,deflate]
Content-Length: [117]
Content-Type: [application/json; charset=UTF-8]
{"name":"Test","type1":"NONE","type2":"NONE","description":null,"comment1":null,"comment2":null}
```

The response I got was:

```
Matched response definition:
(no response definition configured)

Response:
HTTP/1.1 404
(no headers)
```

Comment: Are you using the latest Contract version?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem @marcin
Versions:
verifierVersion, wiremock version and stub runner version =3.0.3

Can someone please help me ? Or author if you have already resolved it please share the fix with us Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Actually I see that the problem is that the regex for json content type is "application/json;charset=UTF-8.*" and the actual is "application/json; charset=UTF-8" (notice the space). You should change your contract to support a regex for that space (e.g. `application/json.*`)